# What is the difference between "\" and "\."?

Tags: android

what is the difference between:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/.SomeDirectory/Other"
```

and:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/SomeDirectory/Other"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the dot sign ('.') before directory or file's name makes it hidden. If no dot, then it is a normal directory.

Answer (score 4):

Hidden files and directories in the UNIX environment have "." as the first character in their name.

for more information: [Hidden files and Directories - Wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments)